# Show that $G_{n+1}/L=\left \{ L_{0},L_{1},...,L_{n} \right \}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So $G_{n}$ is the group with presentation

$\left<s_{1},...,s_{n-1}\mid s_{i}^{2}=1, s_{i}s_{j}=s_{j}s_{i}\text{ if } \left | i-j \right |\geq 2, s_{i}s_{j}s_{i}=s_{j}s_{i}s_{j} \text{ if } \left | i-j \right|=1\right>$.
L is the subgroup of $G_{n+1}$ generated by $s_{1},...,s_{n-1}$. We define $L_{n}=L, L_{n-1}=s_{n}L, L_{n-2}=s_{n-1}s_{n}L,..., L_{0}=s_{1}s_{2}...s_{n}L$. The hint was to consider the action of $G_{n+1}$ on $\left \{ L_{0},L_{1},...,L_{n} \right \}$ by left multiplication. Also, we don’t need to worry about showing that these cosets $L_{i}$ are all distinct.
What is a good way to prove this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that, for all $s_i$ and all $L_j$, $s_iL_j = L_k$ for some $k$.

I won't write out a formal proof, which is messy because of all the indices, but an example should make it clear what is going on. Let $n=6$, $i=4$ and $j=1$. Then
$$ s_iL_j=s_4s_2s_3s_4s_5s_6L=s_2s_4s_3s_4s_5s_6L=s_2s_3s_4s_3s_5s_6L=s_2s_3s_4s_5s_6s_3L=L_1$$

since $s_3 \in L$.